# Swift 3 Firebase user authentication / database login with email password

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is a particular rather than a general 'how do you do....' issue. On my App a user can log in with email and password to a Firebase account, it then takes them to a data entry page with a number of fields. If the user already exists their data is downloaded to the fields where they can edit and save back to the database.

All of this works just fine except for one thing. When I test it and log into an account it downloads existing data from the user. However, if I log out and log in with a different user it still downloads (or displays) the info from the previous login. I have checked the user is actually logged out using " FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener". It is not really an issue where there is a single user on a particular device, but I don't like that it is not working correctly and it would be nice to resolve it. Any help would be much appreciated - maybe I am missing something obvious? :-)

There is quite a bit of code so I have cut it down a little but retaining the main parts. (Small rant. I notice a lot of the time when people ask for more code they tend not to be the ones who actually go on to help. Reputation builders I think! Very annoying).

```
class UserLoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var logoutButton: UIButton!

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

   ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

//======Check if logged in, if so hide login button
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    {
        self.logoutButton.alpha = 1.0
        self.userNameLabel.text = user.email
    }
    else
    {
        self.logoutButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.userNameLabel.text = ""
    }
}

//======LogIn

@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == ""
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)         
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                self.logoutButton.alpha = 1.0
                self.userNameLabel.text = user!.email
                self.emailField.text = ""
                self.passwordField.text = ""
        // ===Segue to DataInput
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue",sender: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This then links to the data entry page:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

var myEmptyField = ""
var myUid = user!.uid

class DataInputViewController:  UIViewController {

@IBAction func unwindDataInputViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

var newAccount: String!
var myLon: String!
var myLat: String!


// ref user data on Firebase
let ownernameRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/users/\(myUid)/ownername")
let nameRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/users/\(myUid)/name")
let typeRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(myUid)/type")

@IBOutlet weak var ownerNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var areaTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var typeTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 //   clearNull()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //reads database to viewcontroller
    if newAccount == "no" {   

    self.ownernameRef.observe(.value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in self.ownerNameTextField.text = (snap.value as AnyObject).description}
    self.nameRef.observe(.value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in self.nameTextField.text = (snap.value as AnyObject).description}
    self.typeRef.observe(.value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in ion}

            }
    }else{
        if newAccount == "yes"{
            let date = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            let startDate = formatter.string(from: date)

            accountSetupDateTextField.text = startDate

         //   clearNull()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solve your problem in five months but perhaps other people need the answer.

I had the same problem today and the only solve I found is:

- set "let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser" as a variable "var"
- change "var myUid = user!.uid" to "var myUid = String()"
- in the viewDidLoad method of your UserLoginViewController put "user = nil"
- in the viewDidLoad method of your DataInputViewController put "user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser" and add "myUid = user!.uid"

After this all work perfectly for me!

Hope I could help somebody with this answer.